# Should I use Core Data as a datasource for an IOS Autocompletion List?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to provide an UITextfield with an autocomplete feature.
After a User types 5 letters a set of  Phrases (200-9000 phrases) is searched for a match.

Since the App is already using core data should I store the upto 9000 phrases in core data or rather use just a text file as the datasource?

one remark. the words list is updateable. if the users enters a new word it is added to the autocomplete list daqasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Core Data would definitely be more efficient from a memory/performance tradeoff (assuming you are using an sqlite store of course) as all phrases wouldnt have to be put into memory before searching begins. If you were to go the text file route, however, you would be loading all your phrases into memory before being able to search through them.

I would recommend you go the Core Data route. If this data is complete separate from the rest of the app's data, you may want to consider just making a new model for it altogether to keep things more organized.

Comment: yes I think your right. I should create a seperate core data model. I am a little affraid that the maybe 9000 inserts when   reading in the list could be slow on a maybe slow iphone 4 (which I do not own so I cannot test this beforehand)

Comment: As long as you perform the fetch on a background thread, I don't think you need to worry about performance too much. Just ensure that your UI doesn't block, and as long as you limit your fetches (to, say, 20 each time a character is entered), you should be fine.